# Bool value not being sent to destination ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

I want to send a bool value, `didAddNewItem`, from my `SearchViewController` to `MatchCenterViewController`, and then run a function depending on the state of the bool value. I attempt to send a `didAddNewItem` value of `YES` to my destination, `MatchCenterViewController`, but it doesn't seem to send correctly, as the function below never runs.

Here's how I'm sending it from SearchViewController (edited to reflect Rob's answer):

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue"]) {

        _didAddNewItem = YES;

        MatchCenterViewController *controller = (MatchCenterViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;

        NSLog(@"we're about to set controller values before segueing to MC");
        // Send over the matching item criteria
        controller.itemSearch = self.itemSearch.text;
        controller.matchingCategoryId = self.matchingCategoryId1;
        controller.matchingCategoryMinPrice = self.matchingCategoryMinPrice1;
        controller.matchingCategoryMaxPrice = self.matchingCategoryMaxPrice1;
        controller.matchingCategoryCondition = self.matchingCategoryCondition1;
        controller.matchingCategoryLocation = self.matchingCategoryLocation1;
        controller.itemPriority = self.itemPriority;

        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
}
```

And here's where I try to make use of it in the destination, MatchViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    if (_didAddNewItem == YES) {
    NSLog(@"well then lets refresh the MC");

    // Start loading indicator
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    // Disable ability to scroll until table is MatchCenter table is done loading
    self.matchCenter.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _matchCenterDone = NO;

    // Add new item to MatchCenter Array with the criteria from the matching userCategory instance, plus the search term
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"addToMatchCenter"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"searchTerm": self.itemSearch,
                                        @"categoryId": self.matchingCategoryId,
                                        @"minPrice": self.matchingCategoryMinPrice,
                                        @"maxPrice": self.matchingCategoryMaxPrice,
                                        @"itemCondition": self.matchingCategoryCondition,
                                        @"itemLocation": self.matchingCategoryLocation,
                                        @"itemPriority": self.itemPriority,
                                        }
                                block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        NSLog(@"'%@'", result);
                                        self.matchCenterArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

                                        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"MatchCenter3"
                                                           withParameters:@{}
                                                                    block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                                                        if (!error) {
                                                                            _matchCenterArray = result;
                                                                            [_matchCenter reloadData];
                                                                            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

                                                                            // Reenable scrolling/reset didAddNewItem bool
                                                                            _matchCenterDone = YES;
                                                                            self.matchCenter.scrollEnabled = YES;
                                                                            //_didAddNewItem = NO;
                                                                            NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                                                        }
                                                                    }];

                                    }
                                }];


     }


}
```

I made sure it was properly setup as a property in the headers of both ViewControllers, so I'm not sure why it's not setting the value in the destination VC correctly. I know for a fact that `addToMatchCenter` function is running correctly without error, so it should be working.

`@property (assign) BOOL didAddNewItem;`

Comment: When are you pushing MatchCenterViewController? If you push this viewcontroller before exicuting block will not assign value for didAddNewItem.

Comment: Issue here is with the block as when segue is perform then your MatchCenterViewController's viewDidload method would be called irrespective of your block being called. So your bool value won't be set and your viewDidlaod method is called which is not having your bool value. So check for your flow and make changed in that.

Answer (score 2):

In your `prepareForSegue`, you are calling `callFunctionInBackground` asynchronously, meaning that it is quite likely that the segue will finish and the new view controller will be presented well before you set `didAddNewItem` in the `block` of `callFunctionInBackground`.

I'd be inclined to change that destination controller to initiate this asynchronous request itself, but have it show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` (or something) to suggest that the dependent request has not yet been finished, and then in the `block` you can remove the activity indicator view and update the UI accordingly.

Comment: Makes sense. I edited my code above to show the changes I made in response to your answer, but for some reason it still doesn't work. It switches to the MatchCenterViewController, but doesn't run the code in the if statement, implying that _didAddNewItem still hasn't been set to YES.

Comment: You have to give us more to go on than that. Do some additional diagnostics to figure out precisely were it's going awry. I'd suggest setting a breakpoints inside each of these completion blocks and then single step through the code and see where it goes wrong.